# Can't connect via SSH / : UNREACHABLE! =>

Tags: server, ssh, authentication

I am trying to deploy a [Leihs instance](https://github.com/leihs/leihs-instance/blob/master/GUIDE.md) but facing issue while connecting to the server via ssh.

My local machine is a MacOS 10.15.7 and the remote server an Ubuntu 18.04.. I created a key on my local machine and copied the key via ssh-copy-id root@server. I can connect to the server via ssh flawless without providing password.

During deployment the ssh connection can not be established and I get the following message:

```
TASK [install system python] ***************************************************
fatal: [server]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "unreachable": true
}

MSG:

Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added 'server, ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@vserver: Permission denied (publickey,password).

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can anybody help me fixing this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like they are using the root user to connect to remote server. Root is normally disabled in Ubuntu, and default ssh configuration shouldn't allow root login.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It was actually an issue created by the deployment script. I found a fix here: https://githubmemory.com/repo/leihs/leihs-instance/issues/8